# Are there are satisfying explanations for why genetic algorithms work?

Tags: algorithms, reference-request, correctness-proof, genetic-algorithms

The following commentator [writes](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=16650185):

> Having studied this extensively back when they were called [Genetic Algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_algorithm), I would like to offer a few insights.
>
> One of the biggest reasons they fell out of favor for more "mathematical" approaches was that no one could really explain why exactly they worked. It makes sense on the surface that "survival of the fittest" and doing something akin to multiple stochastic gradient descents would work, but no one has really been able to produce a mathematical proof as to why.
>
> Since other folks are producing good examples of "explainable AI", I don't know how Genetic Algorithms/programming could be made 'explainable' as to why they achieved an optimal solution other than hand-waving to how evolution works in nature.

[Steven Wolfram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stephen_Wolfram) has published the book [A New Kind of Science](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_New_Kind_of_Science), in which he posits that mathematical proofs aren't relevant to this approach, and the algorithm is itself the science. Many [considered this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1228669/109927) unsatisfactory.

We know that Cellular Automaton [rule 110](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_110) is Turing complete. (And [phenomenal things](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/11880/build-a-working-game-of-tetris-in-conways-game-of-life) have been done with Conway's Game of Life).

My question is: **Are there satisfying explanations for why genetic algorithms work?**

Comment: Your question is problematic: what would evidence for absence of something look like?

Comment: That said, I think there's ample evidence that genetic algorithms *don't* work in the sense of classic algorithms. They are fancy heuristic search algorithms and as such sometimes yield good results, and sometimes bad, and most of the time (if the problem is really hard) you won't be able to tell the difference.

Comment: Words of my former lecturer: "when genetic algorithm works and you know how it works, it's probably when you have a good insight on the problem. In that case, you'll probably be writing a more direct algorithm anyway."

Comment: Thanks @Raphael that’s helpful- I’ll update the question.

Comment: Are all the "many" mathematicians?  Because if they are, that would be a pretty simple explanation of the criticism.  Turkeys don't vote for Christmas, and it would  add validity to your question.

Comment: It's not clear if the commentator intended to use "explainable AI" in a technical sense, but if so, "explainable AI" doesn't mean algorithms with mathematical arguments for why they are optimal. Explainable AI is where the *result* of optimization is something that can "explain" why it makes the decisions it makes. For example, you could use a genetic algorithm to optimize decision trees. The resulting decision tree is explainable AI, because it's very clear why it makes the decisions it does and what may have made it choose differently. Contrast this to the situation with neural nets.